# function similar to Lua nn.Linear() in tensorflow

Tags: lua, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a code from lua to tensorflow. What is the similar function for nn.Linear() in tensorflow. Any replacement or similar function to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `slim.fully_connected` in `tf.contrib.slim`.

In Torch,

```
module= nn.Linear(input_dims, output_dims)
```

is equivalent with

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size] + input_dims, name='real_images')
output = slim.fully_connected(input, output_dims, activation_fn=None)
```

in tensorflow without considering about data's batch opertion.

Please check [tf.contrib.slim documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim).